# Is it possible to create a good UI/UX using only CSS and no Javascript?

Tags: css

Preconditions:
No CMS solution, i.e. no Wordpress etc.
No Javascript/Ajax, i.e. I want a "static" site.
No text shown as images, i.e. I want to be able to edit content myself.

With good UI/UX I mean dynamic user feedback, when a user interacts with the HTML widgets.
Example, http://www.rapha.cc/ is using CSS for menus (which highlight the currently selected). I guess I'm looking for good live examples...

Is it possible to create a good UI/UX using only CSS and no Javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: Of course it is.

More complicated answer: Depending on what you want to do..... CSS can do some mighty funky things, but it does have limitations.

Comment: Do you know if ANY of the top 500 Alexa sites NOT using Javascript ?

Comment: @user77115: That has absolutely nothing to do with having a good interface.

Comment: So, if it's possible, could you please give an example ? My preferences of tools is not in the mainstream, so I have Googled plenty before posting here...

Comment: @user77115: You would have to give an example of the type of effect you are looking for, and then we can say how it is done and whether it will require Javascript.

Comment: Question answered, of course, but still surprised that no wellknown pure CSS example website seems available. Maybe it's not current best practice in webdevelopment ?

Answer (score 0):

As per Karpie yes of course.

From your question though I think you ned to clarify if you want a good UI/UX or a good 'flashy/pretty' UI/UX, they are not the same thing.

The UX can be very good without having any 'pretty' effects.

Comment: So if it's possible, someone should be doing it ? I'm not in the webdesign field, so I guess I'm looking for an example website, created by someone that has the same preferences in tools and solutions as I have.